# cUrl - How to get headers and download file from response of a multpart POST request

Tags: curl

I am able to download the image by this, and view the image properly

```bash
curl -X POST -F "image=@11.jpeg" http://localhost:8080/ -o responseImage.png
```

| % Total | % Received | % Xferd | Average Dload | Speed Upload | Time Total | Time Spent | Time Left | Current Speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 197k | 100 112k | 100 87224 | 1372 | 1042 | 0:01:23 | 0:01:23 | --:--:-- | 33492 |

And I am able to get headers in the terminal through this

```bash
curl -i -X POST -F "image=@11.jpeg" http://localhost:8080/
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Mon, 14 Aug 2023 12:03:23 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-type: image/png
content-disposition: attachment; filename=responseImage.png
x-count: 20
content-length: 114814
```

But when I try to merge both commands I couldn't see the headers and also not able to open the image(The image viewer say "We don't support this format")

```bash
curl -i -X POST -F "image=@11.jpeg" http://localhost:8080/ -o responseImage.png
```

| % Total | % Received | % Xferd | Average Dload | Speed Upload | Time Total | Time Spent | Time Left | Current Speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 197k | 100 112k | 100 87224 | 1372 | 1042 | 0:01:23 | 0:01:23 | --:--:-- | 33492 |

What I want is to receive the header and get information, as well as to download the image also, so that I can view the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-i` means `add the response headers TO THE OUTPUT` and `-o responseImage.png` means `make responseImage.png THE OUTPUT`, and when  you do `-i -o foo.png` , the response headers will be written to foo.png first, so the first thing your image reader will see, is not the PNG header `‰PNG` but rather `HTTP/1.1 200(...)`, which isn't a valid image format, thus your error.

replace `-i -o foo.png` with `--dump-header - -o foo.png` and the response headers will be written to stdout, while the response body will be written to foo.png, as you intended :)